# Adicionar sub propriedade dinamicamente

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, classes

```
class ObjetoSimples{
   var $nome;
   var $cargo;
   var $turno;
}

class ObjetoComposto{
    var $nome;
    var $setor;
    var $equipe;
}
```

Como adicionar novo `nome` com `turno` e `cargo` na `equipe`?

Por exemplo:

```
ObjetoComposto->novo($this->nome,$this->setor,$this->equipe->novo(nome,cargo,turno))
```

Comment: já vi com uso de arrays, mas estou querendo evitar matrizes multidimensionais, e como estou inciando em orientação à objetos, me vi neste complexo de niveis e subniveis de variaveis. Seria possível atualizar a equipe através do ObjetoComposto sem interferir no seu setor e no seu nome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fazer como um *array* associativo realmente é uma solução, até porque um objeto não deixa de ser um. Concordo que é uma bela gambiarra e deve ser evitado a não ser quando realmente faça sentido.

Então é só criar o objeto do jeito tradicional. Primeiro cria um objeto auxiliar, aí inicializa cada propriedade, sendo que a que terá um objeto usará este objeto auxiliar. O básico é assim, não tem jeito.

Outra técnica é criar um construtor na classe para facilitar a criação do objeto. Como o construtor padrão do PHP é muito limitado e criaria outros problemas no código eu prefiro (ainda que isto não seria o ideal em outra linguagem) criar funções estáticas que funcionam como construtores, assim libera o construtor sem parâmetros e permite uma espécie de *overloading* dos construtores.

Então criei um construtor que recebe todos os argumentos necessários para preencher todas as propriedades, inclusive a que é um objeto que será criado nesse "construtor".

Criei um outro construtor que pega só os argumentos para preencher as propriedades e exige que seu código crie uma instância da propriedade que é um objeto. Neste caso, pra facilitar também criei um "construtor" para criar este objeto.

Em outra linguagem isto poderia ser feito de forma mais suave.

Não sei se este é o melhor jeito porque não faço OOP em PHP, mas é o mais óbvio pra mim.

```
class ObjetoSimples {
    var $nome;
    var $cargo;
    var $turno;
    public static function construtor($nome, $cargo, $turno) {
        $obj = new ObjetoSimples();
        $obj->nome = $nome;
        $obj->cargo = $cargo;
        $obj->turno = $turno;
        return $obj;
    }
}

class ObjetoComposto {
    public static function construtor($nome, $setor, $nome2, $cargo, $turno) {
        $obj = new ObjetoComposto();
        $obj->nome = $nome;
        $obj->setor = $setor;
        $obj->equipe = new ObjetoSimples();
        $obj->equipe->nome = $nome2;
        $obj->equipe->cargo = $cargo;
        $obj->equipe->turno = $turno;
        return $obj;
    }
    public static function construtor2($nome, $setor, $obj2) {
        $obj = new ObjetoComposto();
        $obj->nome = $nome;
        $obj->setor = $setor;
        $obj->equipe = $obj2;
        return $obj;
    }
    var $nome;
    var $setor;
    var $equipe;
}

$obj = new ObjetoSimples();
$obj->nome = "joao";
$obj->cargo = "gerente";
$obj->turno = "noite";
$obj2 = new ObjetoComposto();
$obj2->nome = "maria";
$obj2->setor = "fabrica";
$obj2->equipe = $obj;
$obj3 = ObjetoComposto::construtor("maria", "fabrica", "joao", "gerente", "noite");
$obj4 = ObjetoComposto::construtor2("maria", "fabrica", ObjetoSimples::construtor("joao", "gerente", "noite"));
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/02CJtV). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/nrrrppkz-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/OOP/AddProperty.php).

Comment: Muito obrigado Bigown, o construtor2 foi uma bela solução, não havia cogitado esta ideia, mas é exatamente a estrutura que deve ser aplicada, funcionou perfeitamente!